# I am trying to refresh d3.js bar chart for live data from api call, but the chart is getting plotted multiple times

Tags: javascript, api, d3.js

I just want to plot live bar chart using d3.js. I am getting data from API call, which I m calling in every 5 seconds and the data I am pushing into an array. But once I call API, the data is getting stored in to the array continously. But d3 chart is not getting refreshed... How to refresh the d3 graph?

```
 var array=[]
 window.setInterval(function a(t) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: URL + '/get',
            data: {
                Id: t,
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.tok);
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            myJSONT = JSON.stringify(response);
            objT = JSON.parse(myJSONT);
    machine.push({"time" : objt[0].time,"value":  objT[0].value});
    array.push(machine);
    //HERE GOES D3 CODE AND PLOTTED USING array. 

 },5000);
```

Comment: Any help will be great. I am stuck in this part